# Does it make sense to use context in react-redux app?

Tags: reactjs, redux

So, I'm beginner in React world. And I don't understand: does it make sense to use `context` in react-redux app? Or it'll be better to use `connect` function ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Context can be used in any sort of react-redux application.

Both solves different purposes.

**Redux** is a state management tool and often used in one of the following cases.

- If we need to use the **middlewares** between the dispatch of action and the response like *logging* actions, *error* handling, *dispatching* other requests depending on the server’s response.
- If data is coming to the a component from the multiple endpoints.
- It gives greater control over actions in the application. Redux enables tracking actions and data change, it greatly simplifies debugging with its devtools.

On the other hand **Context** provides a way to pass data (globally in the app) through the component tree without having to pass props down manually at every level like translations, themes or anything which will be used across the app.

Based on the requirement, we can choose when to use redux or context to solve different purpose.

Answer (score 2):

You can use context in a react-redux application. For eg., You might want your theme to be in context.

Use Redux, when the data changes frequently and have to pass on to a lot of components (children/siblings). eg. Multi-step forms.

Use State, when you have frequent data changes and the data need not passed to a lot of components or doesn't need for deeply nested children. eg. Forms, UI states.

Use Context, when data needs to be shared in deeply nested children but the data update in infrequent. Login information, preferred language, theme etc.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Why not putting everything in the Redux store then and have only one single source of truth for all your data ?

Comment: let's say I have a form, data for which is submitted. Those data(user inputs) are not used anywhere else in the app. Why should we bloat the redux store? Each update having an action, reducer etc... too much verbose information. Even though this can't be reused.

Comment: Yes. This is good question.

Comment: UI states like this, show hide... these kinds of should not be part of redux. Mostly only one component is bothered about this. Why let the entire app know about this change?

Comment: @BalavishnuVJ I agree that data in forms don't necessarily have to be in Redux store. I was more asking about your point on login information, theme, etc... This could bring confusion if we sometimes put data in context, and sometimes in redux store.

Comment: for, login information. Let's say I only show the user's name and image. This usually change doesn't in the lifetime of the usage. I don't think it makes sense write so much boilerplate code if that is not going to be used again. Same stands for the theme.

Answer (score 0):

It depends of what you want to achieve. Redux store is global for all your application while context is only available from the component in which you created it to all the components in its subtree.

Comment: Context and Redux both are available for the subtree. Usually, people wrap the application with `Provider. So that you get the redux store globally. This could be achieved using context too.

Comment: You are right. We are so used to wrap the root component with Redux store provider that we forgot that we can use it in a different way :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all figure out your need of application, if you want to develop a small web app then you can develop it without using Redux and context API, if you are going for large application then you could think of using any one of them, both are used to manage the state of your application or component. Redux is a third party library and context API is built by Facebook only.